# how do I use nested ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, nested

I named several rows in Excel as Chapter_9 and from those rows i named several rows as Chapter_9_1.
I want to run over all Chapter_9 rows and when I identify rows which belong to Chapter_9_1 to do something else.
any help will be welcome.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you chose this approach, but here is something.

This is based on a Range.Intersect function - it returns the common range of two ranges. In your case, an intersection of range `Chapter_9` and `Chapter_9_1` would return range, in other case it would return `nothing`.

Here is my code

```
Sub Main()
    Dim rngChapters As Range
    Dim rngChapter1 As Range
    Dim rngChapter2 As Range
    Dim rngChapter3 As Range
    Dim rngIntersect As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    ' A1:A15
    Set rngChapters = Range("Chapters")

    ' A1:A5
    Set rngChapter1 = Range("Chapter1")

    ' A6:A10
    Set rngChapter2 = Range("Chapter2")

    ' A11:A15
    Set rngChapter3 = Range("Chapter3")

    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(rngChapters, rngChapter2)

    ' Testing if the ranges intersect
    If rngIntersect Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "empty"
    Else
        For Each cell In rngIntersect
            Debug.Print cell.Address
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can turn this to u function that will accept two strings (range names) as parameters and returns true/false. It depends on what are you trying to do.